# Terminal application erased from Ubuntu 13

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I had a bit of rough time with Ubuntu yesterday when the home screen went blank and no program icons or sidebars were visible. Today after recovering from it and saving the essential data, I have found that the terminal applications packed with Ubuntu has erased itself from applications and instead new terminal applications called UXTerm and xTerm have appeared in its place.

They do almost the same job but have many limitation such as not being able to copy and paste from terminal screen. I really want to get back my old terminal application :(

Comment: Can you tell us what was the old terminal emulator you used?

Comment: Most likely that was [gnome-terminal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/gnome-terminal)? Maybe check if it's still there by typing `gnome-terminal` in one of the terminals you mentioned. If it's not installed you can easily reinstall it with `sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal`. Most likely triggers will reconfigure it as the default afterwards...

Comment: i tried puting in sudo apt-get gnome-terminal ... i get -> E: Invalid operation gnome-terminal

Comment: oh no wao i forgot putting in install between apt-get and gnome-terminal .... teriific it worked i hav my terminal now !!! thanks illuminE

Comment: And just for the record, xterm _does_ have cut and paste, it uses 'Ctrl-Insert' to implicitly copy (selecting something auto-copies) and 'Shift-Insert' to paste (UXTerm may be the same, I've never used it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's not the best solution, but may I suggest that you install [Terminator](http://www.tenshu.net/p/terminator.html).

It's a very well suggested terminal emulator (see [lifehacker article](http://lifehacker.com/5858676/the-best-terminal-emulator-for-linux) and [linux and life](http://www.linuxandlife.com/2013/05/my-favorite-linux-terminal-emulators.html)) that among many things, has the capability to split the terminal screen into many more terminals.

If you are interested, installing it is as easy as an `apt-get install terminator` and setting it as the system default in ubuntu can be done with `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.default-applications.terminal exec 'terminator'`

If you do install it you can read more about it how to effectively use it [here](http://blog.al4.co.nz/2011/05/getting-the-most-out-of-terminator/) and [here](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/terminator-multiple-gnome-terminals-in-one-window.html) (this one is an old guide, but it still holds for the most part)

Comment: heyy thanks for suggesting terminator .. it works fine too.. i see it also has better options such as splitting horizontal, vertical etc .

Comment: Hey @AltanaiBisht glad you liked it. :)

Answer (score 0):

**`xterm`** (and **`uxterm`**) were there anyway, not *replacing* **`gnome-terminal`**, but useful when **`gnome-terminal`** is broken (really).

In practice, there's not a lot of difference between gnome-terminal and [terminator](https://gnometerminator.blogspot.com/p/introduction.html), since almost all of the functionality is in the VTE library which both use.  As they said, beauty's only skin deep.

For select/paste, that's an FAQ (as well as being frequently discussed here).  But the FAQ is the place to go:

- [Why can't I select/paste to/from other programs?](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/xterm.faq.html#xterm_select_clipboard)
- [uxterm - X terminal emulator for Unicode (UTF-8) environments](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/manpage/uxterm.html)